# JQuery UI datepicker ( start weeks from Monday)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery UI datepicker, I know I can customize this datepicker in this way:

```
$("#reserve_date").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: no_disabled_Days
});
```

currently, my datapicker calendar start weeks from **Sunday**, I would like it starts weeks from **Monday**, how to do??

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ firstDay: 1 });
```

[jQuery UI Reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-firstDay); see the link for a slightly more detailed explanation.

For inline reference:

```
Sunday     0
Monday     1
Tuesday    2
Wednesday  3
Thursday   4
Friday     5
Saturday   6
```