# Jquery datepicker start week day

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to start the week on Monday with the next jquery code :

```
       $(function() {


           $.    ("#from").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).val()
           $("#to").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).val()
   });
```

Best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery UI datepicker ( start weeks from Monday)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003362/jquery-ui-datepicker-start-weeks-from-monday)

Comment: Maybe but this is with this simple code. I have found another with parameters but not using it with this one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {



           $("#from").datepicker({ firstDay: 1 },{ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).val()
           $("#to").datepicker({ firstDay: 1 },{ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).val()
   });

    </script>
```