# yadcf - range date filter - jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: datatables, jquery-ui-datepicker, yadcf

is possible to set in this datepicker weeks starts on Monday?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgutbor/hp16ym6z/) to explain this.

The second column (date) is a range date and when you try to select start date in the filter the weeks always start on Sunday.

```
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: there is no date picker in your test page

Comment: Excuse me Daniel, I haven't update the fiddle. Now is correct. https://jsfiddle.net/mgutbor/hp16ym6z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `filter_plugin_options` of yadcf in order to pass the third party plugin its init options, in this case the following will do

```
{   
    column_number: 1,
    filter_type: 'range_date',
    filter_plugin_options: {
        firstDay: 1
    }
}
```

See [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/hp16ym6z/4/) and read [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003362/jquery-ui-datepicker-start-weeks-from-monday)

*Always bet on yadcf*